# Parsing int to a string

Tags: c#

I have a text box called txttotalnum and am trying to parse it to string, it gives an error saying cannot complicity convert int to system.web.ui.webcontrols.text,  please help

```
foreach(mcx.supplierportal.taxregistration _taxlist in edittax)
{
    Txtvatnumber.text = _taxlist.text;
    Txttotalnum = int.parse(txttotalnum.text)
}
```

Comment: Try this: `Txttotalnum = int.parse(txttotalnum.text).ToString()`

Comment: your variables are very confusing.

Comment: do don't parse to a `string` you parse from a `string` and, its implicitly, not complicitly!!

Comment: if you want to assign a value to a textbox, assign it to the text property. You dont need to parse it to int then tostring it. just directly assign the value, ex: Txttotalnum.Text = value.

Comment: camelCase and PascalCase send you their regards.

Answer (score 1):

if **Txttotalnum** is your text box then you are trying to assing int value to your textbox instead of assigning it to the **Text property** of the text box.

So update

```
Txttotalnum = int.parse(txttotalnum.text)
```

To

```
Txttotalnum.Text = txttotalnum.text
```

Comment: What would be the point of this code? Take a textbox value and put it in the textbox it already is? It has no purpose.

Comment: OP Said : **it gives an error saying cannot complicity convert int to system.web.ui.webcontrols.text** so that means he/she is trying to assign value to the textbox. and it is giving an error.

Comment: Read the code. The text he is putting in the textbox is the text from that very textbox. He is doing the integer parse for a reason. Your line of code is completely superflous, it has no effect what so ever, I'd be suprised if the compiler doesn't straight up remove it.

Comment: that is OP's job to identify the same. may be he/she has provided the sample code just to explain.

Answer (score 0):

should be:

```
foreach(mcx.supplierportal.taxregistration _taxlist in edittax)
{
    Txtvatnumber.text = _taxlist.text;
    Txttotalnum.text = int.parse(txttotalnum.text)
}
```

Comment: your code will give an error "Cannot convert source type 'int' to target type 'string'"

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
Txttotalnum = int.parse(txttotalnum.text)
```

To this:

```
Txttotalnum.Text = int.Parse(txttotalnum.Text).ToString()
```

Comment: That's impossible. You get the error you get because you try to turn your integer into a Textbox control. My code doesn't, so you probably didn't copy it properly.

Comment: there is no need to parse to int. You are parsing string to int and then again to string. This is not a good practice.

Comment: SpiderCode: It could be for validation, or formatting. Maybe the textbox has leading zeroes, for example. This will remove them. I agree it's weird to do though.

Answer (score 0):

Better option for you is also checking a value:

```
foreach(mcx.supplierportal.taxregistration _taxlist in edittax)
{
    int outValue;
    Txtvatnumber.text = _taxlist.text;
    if(int.TryParse(txttotalnum.text, out outValue))
    {
        Txttotalnum = outValue.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        // error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`int.parse(txttotalnum.text)` parses the string in `txttotalnum.text` into a `int`.

`Txttotalnum` is a `Text` control.

You cannot assign a `int` to a `Text` control, hence the error.

What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

**1.** You are setting the `Value` to `TextBox` Control directly.
**2.** You are accessing the `Text` of the `TextBox` using `.text` property but it should be `.Text` (if that is not typo in your Question).
**3.** There is no meaning for `parsing` the value into `int` as `TextBox` control only takes `String`.

Try This :

```
Txttotalnum.Text = txttotalnum.Text;
```

but if you really want to check wether the assigning `value` is `int` or not, you can Check using `int.TryParse()` method and if it can not be parsed to `int` just assign the value  zero or display no value.

Try This:

```
int result;
if(int.TryParse(txttotalnum.Text,out result))
Txttotalnum.Text = result.ToString();
else
Txttotalnum.Text = "0";//assign zero or display no value
```